# Spring, подключение MySql

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Как только подключаю к приложению базу данных, сразу ошибки.

application.properties file:

```
  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/telega
    spring.datasource.username=root
    spring.datasource.password=1712
```

Ошибок много, но к примеру:

```
ERROR 16768 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'telega'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
```

at... и много много строк "at"

потом

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'telega'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:318) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'telega'
```

потом опять 2 раза ошибка вот этого HikariPool

а потом

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-05-27 17:18:30.777 ERROR 16768 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

идентично повторяю за spring.io guide.

Comment: вы схему создали? сервис с БД запустили?

Comment: Ещё надо, вроде, либу с драйвером подключения к БД добавить и в пропертях указать диалект для БД.

Comment: Судя по сообщению об ошибке, БД не создана.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем инстансе mysql нету базы "telega".

В mysql консоли выполните

```
create database telega;
```